# Vendor opening balance in suitelet

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I am working in Netsuite on a suitelet. I want to create a CSV report using Suitelet. Suitelet and CSV report is ready with other fields only the problem is with the vendor opening balance field.
I want to get the vendor opening balance in suitelet. How can I get that?

We are currently using **Custom vendor form**. When I customized the form, it does have an opening balance field enabled(‘view’ is ticked) but I cannot see it on the vendor record. I dont know, why this happens? Same is the case with the standard form, when it is in use the opening balance field is enabled but cannot be seen or accessed in the vendor record.

Currently the vendor opening balance can be seen on one of the Netsuite reports but we cannot take values from there.

Comment: Did you check the SuiteScript Records Browser? I suspect you have not because it shows the Vendor record exposes field `openingbalance`. There is no search column for this data, you will need to access it from the  full `nlobjRecord` reference.

Comment: hi,

I did try SuiteScript Records Browser. But no help.

var openingbalance = load_rec.getFieldText("openingbalance");

also gave me blank result.


FYI: I tried getting the value of vendor opening balance in saved search but there is no option where I could get it.

Comment: @SteveK
 var openingbalance = load_rec.getFieldText("openingbalance");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It bugged me that I couldn't get this data, especially considering you said it was available on a report. I thought about this some more and realized it creates a Journal Entry when you create a Vendor and define an opening balance. This means that the data we want should be just a Transaction search away, and it was.

```
var VENDOR_ID     = 9898387,
    MAGIC_JE_MEMO = 'Opening Balance';

var jeResults = nlapiSearchRecord('journalentry', null,

    //  Filter to entity and unfortunately we also need to rely on the Memo field
    [
        new nlobjSearchFilter('entity', null, 'is', VENDOR_ID),
        new nlobjSearchFilter('memo', null, 'is', MAGIC_JE_MEMO),
        new nlobjSearchFilter('creditamount', null, 'isnotempty') ],

    [
        new nlobjSearchColumn('creditamount'),
        new nlobjSearchColumn('entity') ]);

if(jeResults) {
    nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'Vendor ' + jeResults[0].getText('entity') + 
        ' has opening balance ' + jeResults[0].getValue('creditamount'));
}
```

That code will yield the log:

> Vendor SK test has opening balance 666.00